# .NET Core - HttpClient vs RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

I've been scouring the internet all day for a simple comparison, but have yet to find any up to date information regarding the subject.

I recently joined a team working on a project that is using RestSharp for all API calls. I have previously implemented an `HttpClient` via the `CreateClient` method of the .NET Core `IHttpclientFactory`.

I'm looking for objective pros/cons regarding each for calling REST endpoints. Is this simply a matter of preference? Is there any underlying difference in how the `HttpClient` lifecycle is managed between the RestSharp library and the `IHttpClientFactory` implementation?

I have noticed, or at least it appears to me, that I am not able to manage the incoming response on as granular a level, but for the sake of the question being asked, let's just chalk that up to my lack of experience with RestSharp.

Comment: Those are different things, that's why there's no comparison. RestSharp is an HTTP library, quite similar to *HttpClient*. HttpClientFactory on the other hand takes care of HttpClient caching and lifecycle

Comment: Yes. So IHttpClientFactory abstracts the caching and lifecycle of HttpClient, so by implementing the interface via the CreateClient method, you in essence are also using HttpClient, but without the hassle of managing the lifecycle of said HttpClient. If RestSharp has similar functionality baked in, or is in fact just implementing IHttpClientFactory, then why even bother with RestSharp, or any third party library, if it is already mature on the platform being used? That's why I'm interested in pros/cons

Comment: IMO, this question falls into the [Gorilla vs. Shark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/) category of questions.

Comment: We had used RestSharp, now we are using HttpClient (Typed, named and HttpClientFactory), both are great clients, but using the net core one we save a dependency. Why to use a third party? Before there was some weakness in the Microsoft library and it was not so easy to use, so some libraries came up to cover the shortcomings, with net core the things changed, the client is easier to use and it seems stable and performant...

Comment: ..., but that does not make the libraries unnecessary, I would say that if you have an old database with other library is ok, if you are creating a new project with net core, try the oficial one, or if you need some feature that a library makes easier to use, go ahead

Comment: the first thing I would add here is if you need to create a client library to share across .net core and full framework projects, then you have to use RestSharp. Currently HttpClientFactory is tied to the .net core DI framework, which you are not going to have inside legacy projects.

Comment: RestSharp uses HttpWebRequest, by now a legacy class that [uses HttpClient](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9b79ee6db16b27d10a49c6f73b54cf13c38bdcaa/src/libraries/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#L1130) internally

Comment: There's a request to update RestSharp to [Use HttpClient instead of HttpWebRequest](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1406).  
[System.Net.Http.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json) has decent HttpClient Json-helper extensions if that helps.

Answer (score 21):

Some prefer to use **HttpClient** because it is already built into the framework. So there's no need to add extra bloat to your project.

**RestSharp**, like any library, is easier to use because someone already did the hard work and ironed out the problems gotten along the way.

I have used both, and the one is not better than the another. It just depends on your use-case, situation and environment.

I had a **WebAPI** proxy project that needed to call another REST API. I chose RestSharp at first because I was already familiar with it from using it in another project. However, I changed to HttpClient eventually because it uses the same return types as the WebAPI controllers, so it just saved me time from having to convert RestSharp's responses back to a **HttpResponseMessage**.

Of course each one has its pros and cons, it just boils down to your use-case.

Comment: Unless RestSharp uses raw sockets, it uses HttpClient eventually - in .NET Core HttpWebRequest was [rewritten to use HttpClient](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9b79ee6db16b27d10a49c6f73b54cf13c38bdcaa/src/libraries/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#L1130)

Answer (score 6):

I'm using RestSharp for a WindowsForm application because it was easy to implement.

Now I'm using Blazor and the latest updates have pushed me from using a simple WebApi call which looked like this:

```
data = await Http.PostJsonAsync<LocationEntity>("api/GetLocation", data);
```

And now to get the same functionality I have to do this.

```
GridRecords = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<List<LocationEntity>>("api/GetLocations", datalist)
    .Result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<LocationEntity>>();
```

I also have to pass my parameter, which is a simple entity as a List so I have extra close to write.  It's simple code but it adds no value.

So yeah, I'm seriously looking at RestSharp or alternative to simplify what should be a simple WebApi call.

I don't know what such a simple things has to be made so complex.

My 2 cents.  I'm a little behind and now I need to spend a day updating all my WebApi calls because MS decided to change the signature so much.

If I was using a third party I could update my Blazor version without fear of my API logic needing to change.  That is the CON of using one vendor for all your libraries.

Comment: It's probably changed because RestSharp recently got an update to switch out the legacy HttpWebRequest it used under the hood to use HttpClient instead. It's now highly questionable what value RestSharp brings to the table and the breaking in existing code is significant enough to seriously question just using HttpClient directly instead.